# Buying a flat in Spain for using it as residence

Tags: real-estate, first-time-home-buyer, spain

- I am an spanish software developer in his 30s, single, no kids, living and working in another EU country with a decent salary.
- I have saved around 25k€ in the last three years working abroad plus another 30k€ that I saved before in Spain (a mix of long term savings plus inherited money).
- I am planning to work abroad for another two years, that should give me around 15k€ plus on my savings putting them in around 70k€ (provided nothing unexpected happens).
- After this two years I am planning to move back to Spain to live in my hometown.
- Once back in my home region I will be lucky if make half the salary I am making now.

Will it be a good idea to use all those savings in buying a flat once I am back in Spain? Will it be better just to rent a flat and keep the savigs for reserve/investment?

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking us to tell you the future? :)

You don't know what's going to happen in 2 years. You have a goal to move back, might be you won't. You don't have a family now, this could change. And one things pretty much for certain: in 2 years, the spanish real estate market won't be where it is now. And we also don't know what other markets (e.g. interest rates) will do in the meantime.

So, its just not possible to give you a meaningful answer without making a ton of assumptions which, most likely, will turn out to be not true in the end.

In very general terms: if you have the goal to settle in one place for a long time and rents are high compared to purchase prices (i.e. net rental yield upwards of 5%), you should consider purchasing if you can afford it.